# Writing a fast MySQL INSERT query or optimization this query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I written an INSERT query. When running on local server, there's no problem but shows error when running the same query on a live server.

Total data on `labtestdat` --> 51439

Total data on `testmedical` --> 1684

---

## Local Server

INSERT Query:

```
INSERT INTO labtestdata(labid,testid) SELECT '131',id FROM testmedical 
WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT testid FROM labtestdata WHERE labid = '131')
```

Confirmation message:

> 1684 rows inserted.
>   Inserted row id: 67592 (Query took 0.0318 seconds.)

COUNT Query:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM testmedical WHERE id NOT IN(select testid FROM labtestdata WHERE labid = '131')
```

Confirmation message:

> Your SQL query has been executed successfully.
>
> count(id)
>         0

---

## Live Server

INSERT Query:

```
INSERT INTO labtestdata(labid,testid) SELECT '131',id FROM testmedical WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT testid FROM labtestdata WHERE labid = '131')
```

Confirmation message:

> #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

COUNT Query:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM testmedical WHERE id NOT IN(select testid FROM labtestdata WHERE labid = '131')
```

Confirmation message (shown after 20s):

> #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

---

Note: Queries are run using phpMyAdmin

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Ask your server admin. It is probably because of `net_read_timeout` server variable. Usually it is 30 seconds by default.

Comment: but this is not solution , now only 50000+ row on server in future row 1000000+ ,,,

Comment: how to sol this problem , please tell me...

Answer (score 0):

The construct `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` does not perform well.  Turn it into `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * ... )` or use `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have an index on `testmedical` for the `id` column.  It should probably be the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Next, it sounds like `labtestdata` is meant to have a UNIQUE relationship between `labid` and `testid`.  Assuming `labid` is more commonly referred to as a constant, make sure you have a `UNIQUE` key on the table covering `(labid, testid)`.

I'm assuming these columns are all integer (or smallint, etc) types.  If they're defined as text or varchar, that could be hurting performance as well.

If the query is still slow even after making sure you have those indexes, try avoiding the WHERE entirely:

```
INSERT INTO labtestdata
  (labid, testid)
SELECT '131', id
FROM testmedical 
ORDER BY id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  id = VALUES(id);
```

Since the `testmedical` table is not very large, hopefully this would perform well.  Don't run this without making sure you have the UNIQUE key, though.

Note that there can be other factors: if your live environment has a lot of load or activity on these tables, perhaps they are being locked, or this query is exacerbating other performance problems.